# How to change on select individually, while there are many selects

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form that there are many dropdown menus. User selects an option and related textboxes appear. I used `.delegate()` to get each change on `select`s.  But when user changes let say 3rd one, all selects change at the same time,

```
$(function() {
        $("#formbody").delegate("select", "change", function(){             
        var type = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $("input").hide().filter("." + type).show();
        $(":button").show();
        });
    });
```

All selects are dynamically added into divs, with incrementing ids.

```
<div id="div1">
<select id="new">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
</select>
<input class="one" name="first_input"/>
<input class="two" name="second_input"/>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <select id="new">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <input class="one" name="first_input"/>
    <input class="two" name="second_input"/>
    </div>
```

But because I do not know JQuery as I should, I could not figure out a solution.

Comment: For reference, .delegate is now superseded by the .on method in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: thanks thedixon, but i can not figure out .on(), .delegate() has gave what i requested from it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$("input")
```

matches all `<input>` elements on the page. That's why `$("input").hide()` is hiding all of them. You want something more like this:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('input').hide()...
```

to only work with the `<input>`s that are inside your current containing `<div>`.

Also, your `<select>` uses "one" and "two" for the values but your classes are "first" and "second". I think you want your `<select>`s to look more like this:

```
<select id="new">
    <option value="first">one</option>
    <option value="second">two</option>
</select>
```

And you should do something about the duplicate `id="new"` attributes.

You also have `$(":button").show()` but there are no buttons in sight.

Demo of the above fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9fsc5/

Comment: thank you, i have the button for adding extra divs. i did look at your fiddle, but second changes does not effect for a select. how to solve that? ( i am now trying your .closest advice)

Comment: thanks "mu is too short".. selecting closest div helped.. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your select menu's have the same ID. Change the value of the ID's to be unique for each menu and you will have your solution.

```
<select id="new">
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  </select>
  .....
  <div id="div2">
    <select id="new">
      <option value="one">one</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
```

Those select lists have the same ID. all Javascript associated with them will effect both. Change one of those ID values, or use classes, such as

```
$(".new").delegate(etc, function(){ 
  var thisSelectListValue = $(this).val; //use the select list we interacted with
  //your other code will go here
```

Should do what you want now.